# Do abilities that trigger when a card is turned face up trigger when that card is in exile?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a card with an ability that triggers when it is turned face up, such as [Coral Trickster](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Coral%20Trickster), does it still trigger when turned face up in exile, for example  when imprinted on a dying [Clone Shell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clone%20Shell)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the turned face up ability does not trigger when the card is in the exile zone. [Rule 112.6](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Ability) says

> Abilities of an instant or sorcery spell usually function only while that object is on the stack. **Abilities of all other objects usually function only while that object is on the battlefield.**

This ability does not match any of the exceptions, so it does not function when the creature is not on the battlefield.

Comment: Ah, the exceptions list also explains other questions I've had in the past! Excellent, thank you.